# Oracle JET: Passing asynchronous property to composite

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, knockout.js, jet, oracle-jet

I want to pass an array (or observableArray) to a composite like so:

`<add-training-modal id="modal" employees="[[data]]"></add-training-modal>`

`data` is retrieved within the associated viewModel via an asynchronous call:

```
self.data = ko.observableArray();
UserFactory.getUsers().then(arr => {
    self.data(arr);
})
```

The problem: `[[data]]` is passed to the composite before the asynchronous call is finished. That would be fine as long as `data` in the composite is updated. However, this is not the case.

In the composite viewModel:

```
function model(context) {
    //...
    context.props.then(function (propertyMap) {
        self.properties = propertyMap;
        console.log(propertyMap.employees); // is empty []

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(propertyMap.employees); // is full [...]
        }, 500);
    });
}

model.prototype.attached = function(context) {
   context.props.then(function (propertyMap) {
       console.log(propertyMap.employees); // is empty []
   });
};
```

I know that I could retrieve the data from within the composite. But that would not be the answer to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, the composite needs to listen for a change event, correct? Add this code:

```
self.composite = context.element;
$(self.composite).on('employees-changed', function (event) {
    if (event.detail.updatedFrom === 'external') {
        console.log(event.detail.value);
    }
});
```

In the latest version (I haven't tested this for myself):

```
model.prototype.attached = function(context) {
    self.composite = context.element;
    self.composite.addEventListener('employeesChanged',function(event){
        if (event.detail.updatedFrom === 'external'){
            console.log(event.detail.value);
        }
    });
};
```

For lots more info, check out this blog: https://blogs.oracle.com/groundside/jet-composite-components-v-events

It's the definitive guide on Oracle-JET composites.

Answer (score 1):

Ray's answer does the trick.

And there's also another solution. It requires JET v5.0.0+ which was released on April 16, 2018. It comes with a new [composite lifecycle method](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.Composite.html#lifecycle) which is called `propertyChanged(context)`. You can use it like so:

```
model.prototype.propertyChanged = function(context){
    if (context.property === 'employees') {
        this.employees(context.value);  
    }
};
```

(Be aware of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895656/upgrade-to-ojet-5-0-0-issue-ojcorebundle-js-not-found) when you upgrade to v5.0.0.)